# sanitize using policies.json

Tags: configuration, troubleshooting, exit-policies

I am trying to set up a policies.json file and I can't get the sanitize option to work. I want it to clear download history but that isn't working. It isn't showing up under about:policies and when I tested it a download wasn't cleared. What am I doing wrong? I have this in the file:

```
"SanitizeOnShutdown": {
  "Downloads": true,
  "Locked": true
},
```

I know that the file is picky. I have the "Your browser is being managed by your organization." link in settings so I know that the file is being applied. Please advise what is wrong. I am using windows.

Comment: It looks like maybe Tor Browser doesn't support the `policies.json` file: https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/tor-browser/-/issues/31978

Comment: The file is recognized and processed. Most of the settings I've implemented are enforced. I can see that under about:policies and in various locations in the settings. The SanitizeOnShutdown and SSLVersionMin are the only ones not working.